SonarQube Web-API - api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=dynamic-project is not working in sonarqube 10.6
I am using Sonarqube10.6 and I am trying to get these rating values- new_reliability_rating | new_security_rating | new_maintainability_rating | new_security_hotspots_reviewed in this analysis_ratings.txt file using this api /api/qualitygates/project_status but i am not getting any value.
Here is my coplete code-
if (env.TECH == 'Java_Gradle') {
    sh """
    set +x
    sudo chmod +x gradlew
    mv build.gradle.staging build.gradle
    ./gradlew sonar \
    -Dsonar.projectKey=project-java-gradle \
    -Dsonar.host.url=sonar_server_url \
    -Dsonar.token=token_number \
    -Dsonar.projectName="${env.REPO_NAME}"
    sleep 120
    sudo java -jar /app/sonar/sonar-cnes-report-5.0.0.jar -t token_number -p project-java-gradle -m -c -e -f -s sonar_server_url -o /app/sonar/report
    sudo curl -u ${SONAR_USER}:${SONAR_PASSWORD} "sonar_server_url/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=project-java-gradle" | jq -r '.projectStatus.status' > /app/qualitygate_status.txt
    sudo curl -u ${SONAR_USER}:${SONAR_PASSWORD} "sonar_server_url/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=project-java-gradle" | jq -r '.projectStatus.conditions | map(select(.metricKey | test("new_reliability_rating|new_security_rating|new_maintainability_rating|new_security_hotspots_reviewed"))) | .[] | .actualValue' > /app/analysis_ratings.txt
    set -x
    """
}

In this code where i am scanning java_gradle application in sonarqube10.6 server after scanning generate a report for that using cnes report-5.0 then retrieves the quality gate status for that project from a SonarQube server using an authenticated API request and writes this status to a file qulitygate_status.txt
And again using the same api processes the JSON response to extract the actualValue of specific metrics (new_reliability_rating, new_security_rating, new_maintainability_rating, and new_security_hotspots_reviewed) and writes these values to a file analysis_ratings.txt But not getting these values.
When I run this api on to my server to get the json data it gives me only this.
command:
sudo curl -u ${SONAR_USER}:${SONAR_PASSWORD} "http://10.0.5.156:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=dynamic-project-java-gradle" | jq .

Here is the output
{
  "projectStatus": {
    "status": "ERROR",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "status": "ERROR",
        "metricKey": "new_coverage",
        "comparator": "LT",
        "errorThreshold": "80",
        "actualValue": "0.0"
      },
      {
        "status": "OK",
        "metricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density",
        "comparator": "GT",
        "errorThreshold": "3",
        "actualValue": "2.79341"
      },
      {
        "status": "ERROR",
        "metricKey": "new_security_hotspots_reviewed",
        "comparator": "LT",
        "errorThreshold": "100",
        "actualValue": "0.0"
      },
      {
        "status": "ERROR",
        "metricKey": "new_violations",
        "comparator": "GT",
        "errorThreshold": "0",
        "actualValue": "12"
      }
    ],
    "ignoredConditions": false,
    "period": {
      "mode": "PREVIOUS_VERSION",
      "date": "2024-07-04T07:44:16+0000"
    },
    "caycStatus": "over-compliant"
  }
}

But I was also expecting these values- new_reliability_rating | new_security_rating | new_maintainability_rating | new_security_hotspots_reviewed in the json data
